# Change Generalized Time Attribute in LDAP with PHP

Tags: php, date, time, ldap

I am using PHP7 and ldap_modify to change data of a LDAP. I can change text values and even DN-Attributes without any problem. But as soon as I try to change a date field with Generalized Time, ldap_modify() returns an invalid syntax error.

My Timestamp currently looks like this: 20180121120000Z, I also tried 20180121 and the PHP datetime or date.

Thanks for any help.

My Code:

```
<?php
$ds = ldap_connect(/*hostname*/);
ldap_bind($ds, /*binddn*/, /*bindpw*/);
ldap_set_option($ds, 3);
$new = array();
$new["expirationDate"] = 20180307155845+0100; /*Example value*/
$modify = ldap_modify($ds, /*dn of the object*/, $new);
if(!$modify) {
    echo ldap_error($ds);
}
```

The Line with the ldap_modify command produces the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_modify(): Modify: Invalid syntax in [...] on line 7
```

My Question is: How do I change the Generalized Date with PHP in the correct way? The changed value is *not* saved, that is the main problem here...

Comment: You haven't asked a question, provided your code, nor specified the error you are seeing.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated my post according to your suggestions.